# Problema com Function

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Estou tento um problema com meu código para consulta no mysql,
https://gist.github.com/Alkun/d2239eee1514a0dfc16a

Se o usuario digitar algum valor a pesquisa no banco de dados é feita normalmente, porém se ele deixar o formulário em branco meu isset() não funciona.
A mensagem que aparece é:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\manos\resultado.php on line 17

```
<?php
include ("cabecalho.php");
include ("includes/conecta.php");
include ("includes/func.php");
?>

<?php

//Cria a variavel telefone enviada do formulario na pagina painel.php
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

//Verifica se o valor de telefone não é vazio.
if (!isset($telefone)) {
header("location: painel.php");
exit;
}
//Conecta com o banco e seleciona os arquivos para efetuar a contagem.
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pizzaria");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT nome, numero, endereco from clientes where telefone = $telefone");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

//Se a contagem for 0
if ($count == 0) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
Ops! não encontramos nenhum cliente com este telefone,
<a href="painel.php" class="alert-link">tente novamente!</a>
</div>
<?php
die;
//Se a contagem for 1
} else {
if ($count == 1) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-success">
Encontramos 1 cliente com este telefone!
</div>
<?php
}
}
//Mostra todos os resultados encontrados.
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo "Cliente: ". $resultado['nome']. "<br/>";
echo "Endereço: ".$resultado['endereco']. "<br/>";
echo "N°: ".$resultado['numero']. "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Mude o `isset` para `empty`.

Comment: obrigado por editar o post, eu não estava conseguindo adicionar no formato código!

a função Empty() funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado! mas porque o isset() não estava funcionando?

Answer (score 1):

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) verifica se a variável existe e não é nula(NULL), enquanto [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) verifica se o valor não vazio para o php os seguintes valores são considerados como vazio ou false:

```
"" (string vazia)
0 (0 como inteiro)
0.0 (0 como float)
"0" (0 como string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (um array vazio)
$var; (variável declarada porém sem valor.)
```

No seu código faz mais sentido verifica se `$telefone` não é vazia do que se ela existe. Mude essa linha:

```
if (!isset($telefone)) {
```

Para:

```
if (!empty($telefone)) {
```